# Error using std::vector of templated variables INSIDE a struct INSIDE a class

Tags: c++, templates, vector, std

I'm trying to do this:

```cpp
template <typename t>
class MyClass
{
    struct InnerStruct
    {
        std::vector<t> itemList;
    };
}
```

The compiler does NOT like my trying to use `std::vector<t>` this way.

Is this impossible with C++, or do I need to put some syntax around it?  Nothing I try works.

The error I get says:

> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'

I want to call a function inside `MyClass` that uses `InnerStruct` as list of temporary objects for computing something.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/lOPJvb). What is the actual problem you are having? Please be more specific. What does the error message say exactly? How are you trying to use `MyClass` and `InnerStruct`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have you included “#include <vector>”?

Comment: You need a semi-colon after your classes closing brace.

Comment: Thank you WalleyM.  That, idiotically, was it.  I thought I had included <vector> in another header.  If you want to answer the question, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of possible errors here.

Firstly, make sure you `#include <vector>`.

Secondly, you need a semicolon after the closing brace of your class.

Comment: Had the semicolon, my cut/paste missed it in the question... <vector> wasn't getting included in the huge include scramble that this file included.